# Why does my archgun keep refilling its ammo?

Tags: warframe

Sometimes when playing with my archgun in regular missions, I find that my ammo (not loaded ammo) **gets fully refilled** to the amount it had right after deploying the archgun.

[image]

I didn't think of it much until I tried using my Kuva Grattler in arbitration. I found that the ammo (in red circle in image) was getting set **multiple times** to 320 (max amount) before I even managed to use it up. The result was me using the Grattler 40 minutes straight without needing to ever reactivate the archgun.

However, I am **not able to point out why** or when this happens. It doesn't seem to be happening on a regular basis either.

While this is certainly not an inconvenience, is there a system to this ammo refilling that can be used? Can I refill my ammo without having to wait 5 minutes to re-deploy the archgun?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some enemy types drop Heavy Weapon Ammo boxes that restore ammo to archguns.  Universal ammo boxes also do this, such as those dropped by Protea's Dispensary (which is also her Helminth ability, so people can put it on other Warframes).